# Can't build unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, compiler-errors

as im not to fimiliar with these sorts of problems i can only supply the compiler errors and hope you know what they mean... any help is appretiated;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNQ9l.png)
[EDIT] new set of problems: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv9tj.png)

i am using (what i think is the latest webGL player) and have it set to windows and have satisfied the player setting.

tried restarting unity
tried satisfying player settings before build
tried making it a seperate scene folder

Comment: Try removing the scene(s) from the build menu and add them back.

Comment: Do you have any funky names of scenes with non a-z characters

Comment: ill try it, but im not sure if thats the issue. thank for the feed back.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error message you received is indicating that the path you provided for the scene file is incorrect, or maybe even the scene name could be causing problems.

Make sure your scenes and/or scenes folder is in the Assets folder. Also, to be on the safe side, you should always make sure the names of your scenes are not using any characters other than: numbers, a-z, "-"

You want to also make sure that the scene is included in the 'Scenes In Build' list found in the 'Build Settings' window. To add a scene, open the scene in the editor, open the Build Settings, and click 'Add Open Scenes'

Comment: it seems i had other scenes added that the number errors once i removed those it brought up a new set of errors regarding the player settings. ill share the new errors in a new edit of my post.